# How can I retrieve all keys from a flask cache?

Tags: flask, caching

I'm debugging a flask app and want to see which values were stored in my simple cache. Is there a way to retrieve all keys? *(The same way you might with a dictionary...*

```
cache = Cache()
cache.init_app(app, config={"CACHE_TYPE": "simple"})

cache.set("item-1", "red")
cache.set("item-2", "blue")

# I would like to do the following:
# cache.keys()
```

Answer (score 6):

Based on the [source code](https://github.com/pallets/cachelib/blob/master/cachelib/simple.py) for Flask-Caching (Don't use Flask-Cache cause it's very dated)...

There doesn't appear to be a built in method to get all the values without providing the keys, but for debugging you could do something like:

```
>>> for k in cache.cache._cache:
...  print (k, cache.get(k))
... 
item-1 red
item-2 blue
```

This appears to return a value of `None` for expired items:

```
item-1 None
```

`cache.cache._cache` is the dictionary with pickled values.

However you should also be aware that the 'simple' cache isn't really thread safe, as it only uses a dictionary for strorage.  You should switch to a [different backend](https://flask-caching.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#built-in-cache-backends) like Redis for larger apps.

Answer (score 4):

When using `redis` as the backend for `flask_caching` there is no method exposed to query all the keys.

But we can query the `redis` instance ourselves.

From the [source](https://github.com/pallets/cachelib/blob/ea98b2d912bb8e0b0949bf7b8fbd11ec1081657c/cachelib/redis.py#L143)

```py
k_prefix = cache.cache.key_prefix
keys = cache.cache._write_client.keys(k_prefix + '*')
keys = [k.decode('utf8') for k in keys]
keys = [k.replace(k_prefix, '') for k in keys]
print(keys)
values = cache.get_many(*keys)
print(values)
```