# List all the cached keys in Flask Cache

Tags: python, flask, caching, flask-cache, flask-caching

I have written an appliacation using Flask, and am caching the response of various api calls.
following is the configuration of my flask app

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_caching import Cache

app = Flask(__name__)

APICache = Cache(config={'CACHE_TYPE': 'filesystem','CACHE_DIR': "/cache"})
APICache.init_app(app)
```

How do I list all the `key_prefix` of all the cached data that has been stored until now ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I retrieve all keys from a flask cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60118783/how-can-i-retrieve-all-keys-from-a-flask-cache)

Comment: No, `cache.cache._cache` dosen't work for 'CACHE_TYPE': 'filesystem'

Answer (score 0):

In the background, Flask-Caching uses [cachelib](https://github.com/pallets-eco/cachelib/blob/main/src/cachelib/file.py), viewing how the cache system is implemented, filesystem doesn't have a dict or a way to access every key, the only way would be to list the directory, and call the `get` method for every file, like this:

```py
for p in cache.cache._list_dir():
    k = os.path.split(p)[-1] # Getting just the key
    print(k, cache.get(k))
```